# Unit testing the success function of an ajax call in a Jquery plugin using Jasmine framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, jasmine

In unit testing of the jQuery AJAX calls with Jasmine I usually can get by with spying on the success function before passing the options to the $.ajax() function (there are many examples on the net and on this forum about that).

however this time I had a peculiar problem. the options sent to $.ajax where buried deeply inside a jQuery plugin and created by a complex logic, and I my only way to get to the success function was to spy on $.ajax itself and call a fake function.

But now that I had the options, I couldn't call the $.ajax function anymore. so after a lot of web searching and API doc reading this is what I finally came up with to get the data which will come back from the server:

```
it('is going to steal the data returned from the server by ajax',function(){
    var ajaxspy=spyOn($,'ajax');
    ajaxspy.andCallFake(function(options){
        ajaxspy.mysterious_options=options;
    });
    $(myelement).myjQueryPlugin(my_method_which_will_call_ajax_eventually);
    spyOn(ajaxspy.mysterious_options,'success').andCallFake(function(data){
        ajaxspy.stolen_data=data;
    });
    ajaxspy.andCallThrough();
    ajaxspy.plan(ajaxspy.mysterious_options);
    waitsFor(function(){
       return ajaxspy.stolen_data;
    })
    runs(function(){
       expect(data).toHaveSomeProperties();
    })
}
```

Given that there is no way to intercept the options any spy on options.success() before $.ajax is called, could this be done simpler?

Thanks,

Reza

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is the intent of this test? Are you trying to test your jQuery Plugin? Or, is it to run an end-to-end test, where you want to fake the response from the server-side?